# Algebraic Combinations of Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

The question is:

Let S be given by $$S_n = \frac {a_kn^k+a_{k-1}n^{k-1}+...+a_0}{b_kn^k+b_{k-1}n^{k-1}+...+b_0}$$

Prove that $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \frac {a_k}{b_k}$$

Comment: Obviously I messed something up

Comment: Note: I edited your question pretty heavily.  Please check to make sure I did not change your meaning.  Also:  I don't see an actual question in it.

Comment: Why didn't it come out like that for me?

Comment: When you want superscripts or subscripts with more than one character, you put them in {}'s.  thus a_{n-1} compiles to $a_{n-1}$.

Comment: ok, I think I got it.  I just added the question.  Please help!

Comment: Hint:  multiply by $\frac {n^{-k}}{n^{-k}}$.

Comment: ok, I see.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Presumably you mean the limit as $n\to\infty$. Try dividing both numerator and denominator by $n^k$ and then taking the limit. Most of the terms should go to zero and you should be left with the desired answer.